# Adding up header information while querying detailed information | This time it is STRUCT

Tags: google-bigquery

In addition to [Adding up header information while querying detailed information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63567999/adding-up-header-information-while-querying-detailed-information)

I have similar requirement now that the last two fields are STRUCT

```
SELECT 'ABC' username, cast('1234' as int64) QueryID, cast('100' as int64) CPU, cast('123' as int64) IO, [STRUCT(['DB1','DB2','DB1'] as DatabaseReferred,['TB1','TB2','TB3'] as TablesReferred)] Struct_DataType
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC' username, cast('8454' as int64) QueryID, cast('589' as int64) CPU, cast('565' as int64) IO, [STRUCT(['DB1','DB2'] as DatabaseReferred, ['TB3','TB6'] as TablesReferred)] 
UNION ALL                                                                                              
SELECT 'ABC' username, cast('3564' as int64) QueryID, cast('145' as int64) CPU, cast('243' as int64) IO, [STRUCT(['DB3','DB5'] as DatabaseReferred, ['TB4','TB3'] as TablesReferred)]
UNION ALL                                                                                              
SELECT 'PQR' username, cast('6352' as int64) QueryID, cast('737' as int64) CPU, cast('562' as int64) IO, [STRUCT(['DB2','DB1','DB1'] as DatabaseReferred, ['TB6','TB7','TB2'] as TablesReferred)]
UNION ALL                                                                                              
SELECT 'PQR' username, cast('2345' as int64) QueryID, cast('200' as int64) CPU, cast('126' as int64) IO, [STRUCT(['DB2','DB1'] as DatabaseReferred, ['TB5','TB1'] as TablesReferred)]
```

I am looking for output as

```
Username  Count(DistinctQueryID)  Sum(CPU)  SUM(IO)  DistinctDatabaseReferred DistinctTablesReferred 
ABC          3                     834       931           4                         5
PQR          2                     937       688           2                         5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Note; I am using STRUCTS as it is claimed in question and its title (while data sample was - I hope wrongly - constructed as array of structs

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'ABC' username, CAST('1234' AS int64) QueryID, CAST('100' AS int64) CPU, CAST('123' AS int64) IO, STRUCT(['DB1','DB2','DB1'] AS DatabaseReferred,['TB1','TB2','TB3'] AS TablesReferred) Struct_DataType UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC' username, CAST('8454' AS int64) QueryID, CAST('589' AS int64) CPU, CAST('565' AS int64) IO, STRUCT(['DB1','DB2'] AS DatabaseReferred, ['TB3','TB6'] AS TablesReferred)  UNION ALL                                                                                              
  SELECT 'ABC' username, CAST('3564' AS int64) QueryID, CAST('145' AS int64) CPU, CAST('243' AS int64) IO, STRUCT(['DB3','DB5'] AS DatabaseReferred, ['TB4','TB3'] AS TablesReferred) UNION ALL                                                                                              
  SELECT 'PQR' username, CAST('6352' AS int64) QueryID, CAST('737' AS int64) CPU, CAST('562' AS int64) IO, STRUCT(['DB2','DB1','DB1'] AS DatabaseReferred, ['TB6','TB7','TB2'] AS TablesReferred) UNION ALL                                                                                              
  SELECT 'PQR' username, CAST('2345' AS int64) QueryID, CAST('200' AS int64) CPU, CAST('126' AS int64) IO, STRUCT(['DB2','DB1'] AS DatabaseReferred, ['TB5','TB1'] AS TablesReferred)
)
SELECT 
  Username, 
  Count_of_Distinct_QueryId, 
  Sum_CPU, 
  Sum_IO,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT db) FROM t.dbs AS db) AS DistinctDatabaseReferred,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tbl) FROM t.tbls AS tbl) AS DistinctTablesReferred
FROM (
  SELECT -- *
    Username, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT QueryId) AS Count_of_Distinct_QueryId,
    SUM(CPU) AS Sum_CPU,
    SUM(IO) AS Sum_IO,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(Struct_DataType.DatabaseReferred) dbs,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(Struct_DataType.TablesReferred) tbls
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY Username
) t
```

with output

```
Row Username    Count_of_Distinct_QueryId   Sum_CPU Sum_IO  DistinctDatabaseReferred    DistinctTablesReferred   
1   ABC         3                           834     931     4                           5    
2   PQR         2                           937     688     2                           5
```